# Yii2 data migration from migration file

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii2-model

My migration file code/value like below but

```
$model->setAttributes(
  [
    'id' => '1',
    'title' => 'Tag test',
    'slug' => 'ssds',
    'status' => '1',
    'is_archived' => '0',
    'description' => 'sdsdfsd  asfda s fsd fsadfasfdsaf',
    'created_at' => '2017-12-14 00:00:00',
    'updated_at' => '2017-12-14 00:00:00',
    'created_by' => '2',
    'updated_by' => '2',
    'identifier' => 'ssds',
 ],
```

but when I run command in composer it shows error

> Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048
>   Column 'created_by' cannot be null The SQL being executed was: INSERT
>   INTO tag (id, title, slug, status, is_archived,
>   description, created_at, updated_at, created_by, updated_by,
>   identifier) VALUES (1, 'Tag test ', 'ssds', 1, 0, 'sdsdfsd  asfda s
>   fsd fsadfasfdsaf', NOW(), NOW(), NULL, NULL, 'ssds')
>   (E:\xamp-7\htdocs\1712SAM\dev\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php:636)

Comment: Go to Phpmyadmin and set allow null on created_by and updated_by,

Comment: change your `created_by` structure to default `NULL` or `CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: If you try to look at my value maybe get value is present there but it shows null. So why i change that to null.

Answer (score 0):

As case, you set unsafe attributes to AR model and for correct work you need set second argument in **setAttributes()** function to **false**.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#setAttributes()-detail